# Is FieldByName injection-safe?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado, code-injection

I'm talking about Delphi + ADO + MSSQL.
Okay, I know that queries with parameters are quite safe against SQL-injections. 
On the other hand, dynamic queries are quite not safe. 
But what about classic FieldByName methods? Can I safely assign to FieldByName an ABSOLUTELY any string value, without risking to have an injection?

Comment: There's no risk from a injection point of view though, but if you let the user enter the name of the field to be updated for instance, then you'll soon or later get broken your data.

Comment: `.FieldByName` is a function. What do you mean by "Can i assign to a function any random string value" ? Do you mean calling the fanction with abitrary parameter or assigning garbage to the TField object's properties (which?) that the function return value is ?

Comment: I probably used the wrong expression, sorry for that.
I meant - can I use something like SomeDataset.FieldByName('MyField').AsString := 'anything, including even SQL commands' safely?
As bummi and TLama say, I can.

Comment: if database access library u use is safe and would not re-construct flat parameter-less insert SQL, then you're safe. PS. given a bunch of russian delphi-related sites perhaps they would be easier for you than English-using SO

Comment: However that is nothing about `FieldByName`. The totally same code would be used by `Form1.StringField2.AsString := ...` or by `Form1.SomeDataset.Fields[2].AsString := ...` or `Form1.DbGrid3.Columns[1].DataField.AsString := ...` - the `FieldByName` function just does not belong to this question.

Comment: Do you mean `ParamByName()` for binding parameter values?

Comment: The question should be Are the **TField.As** *xxx* properties injection safe?"

Comment: Yes, that's what I actually meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is safe.
Ado is using parameters for Update/Insert/Delete.

You can trace this with SQLProfile, e.g.

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE "test".."Activity" SET "data"=@P1 WHERE "InvokeTime"=@P2 AND "data"=@P3',N'@P1 float,@P2 datetime,@P3 float',1,'2013-04-24 10:46:22.933',0,48607825089780715

exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO "test".."Activity" ("InvokeTime","data") VALUES (@P1,@P2)',N'@P1 datetime,@P2 float','2000-01-01 00:00:00',2

exec sp_executesql N'DELETE FROM "test".."Activity" WHERE "InvokeTime"=@P1 AND "data"=@P2',N'@P1 datetime,@P2 float','2000-01-01 00:00:00',3
```

Comment: @bummi. You mean "safe" don't you?